# How to improve performance of a Retrieval Augmented Generative (RAG) model?

Tags: generative-models, information-retrieval, text-generation, llm

I had implemented a Retrieval Augmented generation (RAG) model on the Healthcare CSV file. The model has to give answers to natural language queries based on the data provided. After implementing the model, when the questions asked it was performing well for all questions except the following type of questions:

1. How many patients are there?
2. How many male patients are there?
3. List all the patients who checked out today

These type of counting questions are not answering well. Is there any improvements or additions I can make so that my model would run fine!

BTW, I am implementing it using langchain and huggingface embeds. I am also using google's palm AI as llm.